# Yii: получение информации из связаных таблиц в разных базах данных

Tags: activerecord, php, yii

Есть две таблицы с логически смежной информацией, но в разных базах(унаследовал от предыдущих разработчиков).
Есть две модели для этих таблиц( Object, Device).

```
class Object extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'device' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Device', '', 'on' => 'device.id = t.device_id'),
    }
}
```

Такой способ подходит только для [жадной загрузки](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.arr#sec-2),
а при обычной выкидывает исключение (Unknown column 't.device_id')
Постоянно дёргать все данные нет смысла, но как ещё можно это сделать не представляю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, если данные в разных базах, то и в конфигах есть подключение к двум БД.

**config/main.php**

```
'components'=>array(
    //…
    'db'=>array(
    ...
    ),
    'db2' => array(
    ...
    )
...
```

---

Тогда для AR, который тянет данные из другой БД (судя по коду - Device) укажите в модели:

**Device.php**

```
class Device extends CActiveRecord{

    public function getDbConnection()
    {
        return Yii::app()->db2; //Подключение к второй базе
    }
    // А так же укажите имя таблицы с БД
    public function tableName(){
         return 'db2.device';
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Тогда в **Object.php** Должно быть достаточно:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'device' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Device', 'id'),
}
```

Comment: @dekameron всё это было сделано, по почему то мозг решил что всё работать должно по другому. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста :)